# How to use getParameter in jsp the safe way

Tags: java, security, jsp

I'm using getParameter to get content from URL to the page.

```
<p>name <%= request.getParameter("name") %></p>
```

What content schould I avoid (ex. script tags)?

How should I validate it?

I'm working in JSP.

EDIT:

For today I just strip html tags:

```
variable.replaceAll("\\<.*?>","");
```

Comment: Duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsp+xss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use scriptlet in jsp its not good practise

```
<p>name <c:out value='${param.name}'/> </p>
```

you should take care of [*XSS attack*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) [`c:out`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/products/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/out.html) will escape xml

To escape javascript injection you can Use [`StringUtils.escapejavaScript()`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.1/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html)

Comment: It doesn't work "on my place". When I pass in my url var=%3Cscript%3Ealert('true')%3C%2Fscript%3E the script runs.